# Retrieve Your Gmail Emails Using PHP and IMAP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I've tried this code from [David Walsh Blog](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap):

```
<?php

/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'davidwalshblog@gmail.com';
$password = 'davidwalsh';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '&lt;div class="toggler '.($overview[0]-&gt;seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'"&gt;';
        $output.= '&lt;span class="subject"&gt;'.$overview[0]-&gt;subject.'&lt;/span&gt; ';
        $output.= '&lt;span class="from"&gt;'.$overview[0]-&gt;from.'&lt;/span&gt;';
        $output.= '&lt;span class="date"&gt;on '.$overview[0]-&gt;date.'&lt;/span&gt;';
        $output.= '&lt;/div&gt;';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '&lt;div class="body"&gt;'.$message.'&lt;/div&gt;';
    }

    echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

But when I tried to run I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /Users/Nathan/Sites/gmail-test/main.php on line 31

Comment: You've copied that from some website. See how it has lots of `&gt;` strings in it. That should be `>` greater than signs. Also the HTML in the quotes is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copied the code incorrectly and ended up getting a whole bunch of html entities mixed in with the code. Compare your code with what is in the blog to fix the problem.

---

Update (I think I got them all):

```
    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
```

Comment: I've used the `Copy` button that the blog provides

Comment: The copy button wouldn't even work for me, I have had problems with copying code from this blog myself in the past.

Comment: Now I get this: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in /Users/Nathan/Sites/mailgregator/main.php on line 9`

Comment: Your copy of PHP doesn't have `imap` installed. I don't have any experience in installing extensions to help.

Comment: You need to make sure the imap extension is installed. How you do that depends on your environment and if you have access to modify something like that.

Comment: How did you install php on your machine?

Comment: If the library is already there, than all you need to do is edit php.ini to enable the extension. Look for the extensions section in the file and remove ; before the IMAP one. Then restart apache. If you dont have it, I'm afraid I wont be of much help installing it on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that it didnt copy right.

```
$overview[0]-&gt;seen
```

Should be

```
$overview[0]->seen
```

There are a few other similar errors.